# Can there be non-isomorphic fundamental groups of equivalent Galois categories?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, galois-theory, profinite-groups

It is known that if $(C, F)$ is a [Galois category](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BMQ) then there exists an equivalence $C \cong \pi_1(C, F)-FinSets$ between $C$ and the category of finite sets with continuous actions of $\pi_1(C, F) := Aut(F)$. At the same time, it is also known that if $G$ is a topological group and $oblv_G: G-FinSets \to FinSets$ is the forgetful functor from the category of (discrete) finite sets acted on continuously by $G$ to that of finite sets, then $Aut(oblv_G)$ is the profinite completion of $G$ (cf. https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BMU). Furthermore, if $G$ is a topological group and $F: G-FinSets \to FinSets$ is an exact functor, then it is necessarily isomorphic to the forgetful functor $oblv_G$ from before (cf. https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BMV)

With all the above in mind, consider $\Gamma_{\mathbb{Q}} := Gal(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$, which is known to not be isomorphic to its profinite completion (as it has non-open subgroups of finite indices, such as $Gal(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/K)$ with $K/\mathbb{Q}$ being an infinite algebraic extension) along with the Galois category $(Sch_{/Spec \mathbb{Q}})_{fet}$ of schemes finite étale over $Spec \mathbb{Q}$, which we equip with the usual fibre functor $Fib_{\bar{\mathbb{Q}}}$ given by $Y \mapsto Y(\bar{\mathbb{Q}})$. There is an equivalence of Galois categories $(Sch_{/Spec \mathbb{Q}})_{fet} \cong \Gamma_{\mathbb{Q}}-FinSets$, but since $Aut(Fib_{\bar{\mathbb{Q}}}) \cong \Gamma_{\mathbb{Q}}$ while $Aut(oblv_{\Gamma_{\mathbb{Q}}}) \cong \hat{\Gamma}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ while $\Gamma_{\mathbb{Q}} \not \cong \hat{\Gamma}_{\mathbb{Q}}$, the fundamental groups of these two equivalent Galois categories are not isomorphic.

My questions are then, is what I have observed above true, and if so, what might cause two fundamental groups of two equivalent Galois categories to be non-isomorphic ? If not, then where did make a mistake ?

Comment: Is the equivalence compatible with the fibre functors? (this may be implicit in the notion of equivalence of Galois categories, but I have to ask)

Comment: @DavidRoberts Yes it is.

Comment: If $G$ is a *topological* group and the finite $G$-sets are *continuous*, then this leads to the *topological* profinite completion: the limit over $G/U$ for all *open* normal finite index subgroups $U \trianglelefteq G$. In that case, any profinite group is isomorphic to its profinite completion. This is the notion used in Tag [0BMQ](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BMQ), right before the lemma you linked (0BMU).

Comment: If $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is infinite algebraic, then $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/K)$ is not of finite index in $\Gamma_\mathbb{Q}$.